# How to define a function that replace a vector of typos for NA's in a df?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am trying to replace a set of typos in a `df`,

This is what I've got so far:

```
master_df <- invisible(
  data.frame(lapply(master_df, 
                    function(x) replace(x, as.matrix(x) == c("?", '-',''), NA))))
```

However the output looks as follows:

```
#  a    b    c
#1        <NA>
#2 ? <NA> <NA>
#3 1    2    1
#4 2    3    2
#5 3    4    3
```

And throws the next warnings:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In as.matrix(x) == c("?", "-", "") :
> longitud de objeto mayor no es múltiplo de la longitud de uno menor

> 2: In as.matrix(x) == c("?", "-", "") :
> longitud de objeto mayor no es múltiplo de la longitud de uno menor

> 3: In as.matrix(x) == c("?", "-", "") :
> longitud de objeto mayor no es múltiplo de la longitud de uno menor

The idea is that the set of typos `c('?', '-', '')` are replaced by `NA` in the whole df.

How could I accomplish this task?

### data

```
master_df <- structure(list(a = c("", "?", "1", "2", "3"), b = c("", NA, "2", 
"3", "4"), c = c(NA, NA, "1", "2", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: You could check out `makemeNA` from [the SOfun package](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun). `library(SOfun); makemeNA(master_df, c("?", "-", ""))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `%in%` instead of `==` as `==` is elementwise comparison operator

```
library(dplyr)
master_df2 <- master_df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), 
  ~ replace(., . %in% c("?", '-', ''), NA_character_))) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
master_df[] <- lapply(master_df, function(x)
      replace(x, x %in% c("?", '-', ''), NA_character_))
```

Or using `gsub`

```
master_df[] <- gsub('^(\\?|-|)$', NA, as.matrix(master_df))
master_df <- type.convert(master_df, as.is = TRUE)
```

---

A better option is to specify `na.strings = c("?", "-", "")` while reading the data with `read.csv/read.table`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try the code below

```
master_df[] <- replace(as.matrix(master_df), as.matrix(master_df) %in% c("?", "-"), NA)
```

which gives

```
> master_df
     a    b    c
1           <NA>
2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3    1    2    1
4    2    3    2
5    3    4    3
```